# Quero colocar mais de um paragrafo no meu xml android, tem como?

Tags: java, android, xml

Estou querendo fazer algo bem simples. Quero que quando o usuário pressione o botão "msg" apareça uma mensagem com pelo menos dois parágrafos curtos logo abaixo do botão, mas estou encontrando dificuldade em colocar as informações dentro de um TextView pois o mesmo não me deixa formatar o texto da forma que quero e, quando coloco todo texto dentro do TextView o parágrafo fica todo quebrado.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

**xml:**

```
 <LinerLayout
 android:layout_width = "match_parent"
 android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
 android:background = "#ddd"
 android:orientation = "vertical">

<Button
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text ="aperte!"
 android:onclick = "imprimirTexto"/>

 <TextView
  android:id = "@+id/textoTextView"
  android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height = "wrap content"
  android:layout_gravity = "center"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

**java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
 private TextView texto;
 public void onCreate(Budle saveInstanceState){
   super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);

  texto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textoTextView);

}
public void imprimirTexto(View v){
  texto.setText("meus paragrafos ficam aqui");
 }
 }
```

Comment: Como está a construir essa mensagem? É um *AlertDialog*? [Edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/101889/edit) a sua pergunta e inclua o *xml* dele.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem duas possibilidades:

- Adicionar outro *TextView* ao *layout* e repartir o texto por os dois.
- Colocar um valor em *dp*(ex.: `100dp`) ou `match_parent` em `android:layout_width`.
  No caso do valor em *dp* são criadas as linhas necessárias, com o comprimento indicado, de forma a apresentar o texto todo.
  Se usar `match_parent` são criadas as linhas necessárias, com o comprimento do *layout*, de forma a apresentar o texto todo.

Comment: obrigado, foi bastante util.